# ffmpeg 1 image with many frames

Tags: ffmpeg

Is that possible to create thumbnails of video using ffmpeg in this format:

[image]

I need to output a single image with vertical shots every 10 seconds.

I know only how to create one image with one frame:

```
 <?php 

$ffmpeg = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg';

$video = '1.mp4';

$image = '1.png';

$interval = 1;

$size = '300x210';

$cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss $interval -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s $size $image 2>&1";       
$return = `$cmd`;

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with one `ffmpeg` command.

## Example

[image: Alone in the Wilderness]

```
ffmpeg -i alone_in_the_wilderness.mp4 -filter_complex \
"select='isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,10)',yadif,scale=240:-1,tile=1x3" \
-vframes 1 -t 30 -q:v 4 strip.jpg
```

## Example with borders

[image: Example with borders]

```
tile=1x3:margin=10:padding=10
```

## Also see

- [select](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#select_002c-aselect), [yadif](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#yadif), [scale](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale), [tile](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) filters documentation
- [Combine multiple images to form a strip of images ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/a/625627/110524)
- [FFmpeg output screenshot gallery](https://askubuntu.com/a/377630/59378)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a single image with one frame every 10 seconds with ffmpeg (e.g. 1.png, 2.png, 3.png) in a for loop and then [merge the images horizontally using imagemagick](http://www.phpied.com/command-line-css-spriting/):

convert 1.png 2.png 3.png -append vertical.png